# How close the soldering joint for pcb?

Tags: pcb-design, soldering, pcb-assembly

I am soldering a 5-12V 5-8amp max electronic to a pcb board, without a schematics. I just want to ask how far should each joint in PCB board? what I mean is for example a cathode and anode when soldering a led emitting diode how far should each pin be? I am worried that a arc electric may travel because of close contact to one another, that its impossible to extend for other electronic pin like mosfet and jb connector. [image]

Comment: At these low voltages, if your eyes can see a space, you are fine. There won't be an arc.

Comment: For low voltage, 0.1mm is enough.

Comment: A bigger concern is that most of these joints are cold and won't stand oxidation nor physical force very well. I've done more sloppy solder jobs than I can count myself - out of experience from my own mistakes in the past I'd strongly recommend to learn how to do it proper from the start. It will save you lots of time troubleshooting broken prototype boards.

Comment: @Lundin I am using lead free solder would be the case maybe? Anyway I still newbie to soldering but would flux help?

Comment: @NormOnly This isn't caused by lead free solder. My boards looked exactly like this when I was a newbie too. The thing is, we shouldn't treat solder as some fancy hot glue :) The purpose isn't just to hold things together mechanically, but also connect them electrically and that the joint will endure over time. Simply put, melting the solder isn't sufficient, it should _wet_ across the _two_ metal surfaces you are connecting. The majority of the joints in the picture have not done this.

Comment: So don't use the tip to "melt solder". Its purpose is to heat the two metal surfaces so that the solder melts against them upon touch. In theory the solder iron tip shouldn't even touch the solder (kind of impossible in practice). And yes, separate flux from a flux pen etc helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum breakdown voltage for a gap of any size in air at 1 bar is about 360V. That minimum occurs with a gap of about 8um. Image from 2006 paper "[Electrical breakdown across micron scale gaps in MEMS structures](https://doi.org/10.1117/12.646508)"

[image]

0.008mm is a very small gap so basically you don't need to worry about it. Of course if conductive debris or liquid falls on the board it will be more likely to cause problems with a narrow gap.

---

Mains voltage is another matter, and it's good to maintain gaps in the >8mm range, perhaps more, depending on various factors.

Comment: You still can't get arcs in air from mains voltage, right? You just want large gaps in case of spills, accidental shorts, dust contamination, etc?

Comment: @user253751 Engineering for what *should* happen is easy, engineering for what does happen only sometimes is not so obvious. You can't get arcs in air from 240 V rms, or 340 V peak. However, mains will frequently have 1500 V spikes on it, and these can jump significant gaps.

Comment: extending your plot, 1500V should be able to jump about 0.3 mm or less. That doesn't really explain the remaining 7.7mm. But thanks for pointing out that power surges happen.